# NetSuite - Create a Custom NetSuite CSV Import Field

Tags: netsuite, import-csv

I have two main questions as I am an extreme beginner with NetSuite.

I have an excel spreadsheet which has a tab known as "Individual", however there is no default individual field to map it with while field mapping. How would I go about creating a mapping for a custom "Individual" tab?

In addition, I am getting an error when trying to import my test file; it is under the language tab and it states "Invalid language reference key English." I understand that this has something to do with clicking the pence icon next to the Language tab and deselecting "names" to "internal id", but it does not give me that option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some record types have a native individual field. What kind of record are you importing?

Comment: Im importing a customer list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom field all together, you need to go to

> Customization-->Lists-->Entity fields

. To make it mappable via CSV, you just need to apply it to the record you wish to import it to,

> (Applied To-->Customer)

and make sure it's on the correct tab of the record.

> (Display-->Subtab/Display Type)

When importing a customer list, isperson is a default, required field. This is a T/F value, so this should be what you're looking for. I would double check and make sure that the form you're using for customers contains this field and is not hidden or disabled.

Once you've done that, you can also check your advanced settings on the CSV import (before you get to individual field mapping), to make sure you're mapping to the correct form with all the fields that you need.

As for the language, I believe that for Netsuite, the correct would be `English (U.S.)`, if that's the type of English that you're importing.